# predictive clustering trees in Python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, regression, forecasting

I am faced with a time series forecasting cold-start problem, specifically I am forecasting energy consumption of businesses where historic consumption data is available only for training but not new businesses. What I have for new (and existing) businesses is metadata such as business type, turnover etc.

I am trying to approach this problem as a multi-outcome regression where the predictors is represented by the metadata, and the outcomes are each time point in the consumption time-series. Thus, the outcomes are correlated. Some articles mentioned **Predictive Clustering Trees** (see [this](http://cig.fi.upm.es/articles/2015/Borchani-2015-WDMKD.pdf) and [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/regression-models-with-multiple-target-variables-8baa75aacd?gi=41d945b5a390) articles for example) as a possible solution to this problem.

Do you know if there is an implementation in Python or any similar algorithm? Alternatively, do you know of any other algorithm already implemented in Python that could be used for cold-start forecasting/multi-output regression?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you examined the possibility that the solution you are looking for is a time-series analysis (not multiple, but a single one which describes your time series data)?

Comment: Could you please expand on that? Notice that I have no historical data to use for forecasting - I just have historical data of other (possibly similar) businesses

Comment: Yes, you have no historical data on the bussiness but similar, what I meant was that maybe you could do predictions on your known bussinesses and then assign the new bussiness to a (modified) trajectory.

As an example:
You forecasted the bussinesses A, B and C for the next 3 months.

You have to forecast D without data, you find (with your metadata) that bussiness D is similar to B, so you assign B's forecast to D and modify it with a multiplier.

$Y_{(D,t+1)} = \alpha Y_{(B,t+1)}$

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you. At the moment I'm doing a similar thing using K nearest neighbours regression (i.e. taking the average consumption for the K nearest neighbours to my target customer). I am not very experienced in timeseries analysis, could you please tell me how I would get that multiplier?

Comment: The multiplier could be obtained comparing between bussinesses which belong to the same group, and how do I know that they belong to the same group? by clustering

Comment: I don't seem to understand.. if you have established that D is "similar" to B (e.g. through KNN or clustering) and you assign B's forecast to D, why do you need to further multiply by a multiplier? Thank you

Comment: I don't know your data, but I could imagine that you have information which allows you to say B and D are similar in terms of being in the same economic sector, in the same city/country, stablished in the same year, etc.

But also you could have information that tells you about size, like number of employees, number of clients, etc, which tell you about a greater energy consumption.

At the end, you could forecast B 3 years ahead, and you know B and D's number of exployees. $\alpha$ is 0.5 because D has half the amount of employees B has.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you I understand now and this is exactly what I'm doing at the moment. I was looking for a model that could provide me with more "personalized" predictions, thus I was keen on exploring different approaches. Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

A python implementation of multivariate predictive clustering trees.

Features
Support for various predictive modelling tasks (binary, multi-class, multi-label, hierarchical classification, single- and multi-target regression).
Supervised and semi-supervised learning.
Handles missing values in the data seamlessly.
Installation
You can install the package directly from the git repository:

pip install git+https://gitlab.com/TStepi/spyct.git
https://github.com/knowledge-technologies/spyct